# Drop shadow hides when Qt::FramelessWindowHint is set

Tags: c++, qt

Several times I have tried to create an application with no OS provided border, but after hours of effort, I threw the idea. The problem is that when I set `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` to the widget, create an instance and show it, it hides its shadow. Here's an example I'm working on.

[image: Widget without shadow]

In this example, you can see that there's no drop shadow around the widget. But there's drop shadow inside the holes. Below is provided code snippet from the constructor of the widget, which makes the shadow inside the holes.

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(// some params)
{
  ...

  setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
  setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
  setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
  QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect;
  effect->setBlurRadius(5);
  effect->setOffset(0, 0);
  setGraphicsEffect(effect);

  ...
}

// main.cpp

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MyWidget w;
  w.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

But how to make it possible drawing drop shadow around the widget?

Comment: Please, provide a complete and minimal example.

Comment: @RomhaKorev what you expected is missing?

Comment: How do you paint the green background: in `MyWidget` class or it's child (with a pixmap, paintEvent, etc.)? How do you paint the holes (with a mask, it's part of the background image, etc.)? If you provide a complete example to reproduce your provide (a minimal widget with a hole and the background), I could provide you the right answer.

Comment: All the stuff is drawn in `paintEvent` function using `QPainter`. No bitmaps and images used. The holes are made using `QPainter::setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Clear)`. I don't think there are more details necessary to answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be the case that you have just set attributes to wrong properties. In case you are inheriting [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) instead of [QDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html), this also might be the reason for the weird behavior you experience.

For instance, when implementing some custom view based dialog, it is better to provide default central container with some layout, and put styles on the container, not on the dialog in order to avoid OS-related or Qt issues. Also, it is advisable to inherit [QDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html) itself instead of [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) if you want custom dialog introduced, since Qt does lots of work for you behind the scenes related to positioning, setting modality, and so on. Thus, standard Qt behavior should be preferred.

Now for the example, see it below:

```
// ShadowedDialog.h
#pragma once
#include <QDialog>

class ShadowedDialog
    : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ShadowedDialog(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~ShadowedDialog();
};


// ShadowedDialog.cpp
#include <QGraphicsDropShadowEffect>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

#include "ShadowedDialog.h"

ShadowedDialog::ShadowedDialog(QWidget* parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    // Set your own window flags, but don't forget to keep the default ones for the dialog.
    this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::NoDropShadowWindowHint);

    // Translucent background is also needed in order for the shadow to work.
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);

    // You would never need to do that, but this will make sure example will be visible enough.
    this->setFixedSize(400, 400);

    // Then, UI is setup.
    auto container = new QWidget();
    container->setObjectName("container");
    container->setStyleSheet("#container{background-color:#ffffff;border:1px solid #000000;}");
    auto layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(container);
    this->setLayout(layout);

    // And finally, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect is put with red drop shadow.
    auto effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
    effect->setBlurRadius(5);
    effect->setXOffset(5);
    effect->setYOffset(5);
    effect->setColor(QColor("#ff0000"));

    container->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
}

ShadowedDialog::~ShadowedDialog()
{
}
```

The example is pretty simple, and basically does the following:

1. It sets some container having white background with black border.
2. Then, [QGraphicsDropShadowEffect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsdropshadoweffect.html) is set. And probably, this is the shadow you want on your dialog.

The result looks like this (tested on Windows 7):

[image: Very simple Qt dialog with red drop shadow on Windows 7]

Generally, the main thing here is to set your styles on child of the dialog, not on the dialog itself.